# Smart Querying in Django, ManyToMany relationships with User

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

I'm working on an app that currently has a lot of ManyToMany relationships (and will eventually have even more), and I'm trying to think of clever ways (read: the right ways) to accurately query the ORM for JOINed data.

Here's a sample of what I have and what I need to do. I apologize for the pseudocode.

```
ProjectModel:
    owner = ForeignKey(User) #just one user
    people = ManyToMany(User) #multiple users and theoretically can also contain the owner
```

Now what I *want* to query is a list of every User who is a "people" in projects that the Current User owns.

I have no real clue how to do this. __contains doesn't really seem suited for this... so I think my options are basically down to just querying every project and doing the iterations myself. But it would be much more enriching if I knew how to get this via ORM/SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# users in projects owned by request.user  
users = User.objects.filter(projectmodel__owner=request.user).distinct()
```

If there are a lot of m2ms, and you had defined a `related_name` in your `people` field, that's what you would use in your reverse lookup instead of `projectmodel`.

Comment: Brilliant. Skillfully Done. That's exactly what I was looking for. Seems to work.